# Блокировать кнопку "отправить" в форме регистрации

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, как реализовать так, чтобы кнопка "отправить" блокировалась, пока в нужное мне текстовое поле не будет внесено нужное мне слово?

Comment: А **return false;** уже не работает? Или вы не знаете, как сравнить значение поля с нужным вам словом?

Comment: и то можно обойти, если JS офф

Comment: @vinnie - всё что на клиенте можно обойти.

Comment: в html5 есть аттрибут required http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/EHStf/

Comment: да блин не не валидацию полей надо, на счет html 5 там если в поле не тыкать то и проверять он не будит )) ))))

Comment: >не валидацию полей надо

Перечитайте свой вопрос, однако. Или у вас какое-то своё понимание слова "валидация".

В любом случае предлагаю решать обратную задачу: разблокировать кнопку как только в нужном поле окажется нужное значение. В такой постановке понятно что делать?

Comment: почему это не будет, вполне себе проверяет. по крайней мере в ff и chrome

Comment: Может ему просто нужно [это][1]?


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled

Comment: Если @Bars прав, то на css можно сделать [примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/EHStf/2/)

Comment: Ставите кнопке атрибут disabled, а на js при определенных условиях убираете его

Answer (score 1):

Например, если ввел больше 10 символов в поле. На основе примера, дальше, сам разберешься.

```css
$("#text").on('input',
function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length > 10) {
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', false);
  }
}
);
```

```html
<input type="submit" disabled value="Кнопка" id="btn">
<input type="text" id="text">
```

Comment: В вопросе JQuery не упоминался.